# The meaning of "set up" in this context?

Tags: semantics

What is the meaning of the phrasal verb "set up" here:

> Make sure to **set up** the issue the business had and needed to solve.

Comment: About all that can be said, lacking any significant context, is that it *probably* refers to preparing for discussion of the "issue".  "Set up" has many different meanings.

Comment: It should be more clearly written.

Answer (score -1):

**set up**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/set+up) v.tr.

> 6a. To concentrate or direct or focus

As in:

> Make sure to **focus on the issue**(s) the business had and needed to
>   solve.